# Best way to create an object listening framework?

Tags: java, object, listener

Note, this question is not relevant to any other questions I've seen on this site. I have not found a duplicate.

I'm working on the framework for my 3D game engine, but before I go into the rendering stuff, I'm implementing utilities such as object listening for certain events.

I was thinking that using an interface called Listener and having any methods added with the annotation "Handler", and the method would be similar to this:

```
@Handler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event) {}
```

This looks seemingly close to Bukkit's event handling used for enabling plugins to do certain actions on an event. I could then use this sort of framework to do achievements, task completion, and so forth.

I think there'd be a better way to do this, but this is the only way I can come up with.

If anyone could help out, it'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use custom events, as described [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077333/core-java/mr-happy-object-teaches-custom-events.html), or use Guava's [EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained).

I prefer Guava's EventBus as it provides a nice abstraction as to how events are handled. You can easily switch from sync to async handling without making too many changes.

Answer (score -1):

i think factory pattern will be ano[t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)her choice. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

```
public class PlayerFactory {
    public static Player createPlayer(){
        //handle event
        return new Player();
    }
}

public class Player{
    private Player(){}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this response is not close to being relevant to my question.